# python asyncio - cancelling a `to_thread` task won't stop the thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio

With the following snippet, I can't figure why the `infiniteTask` is not cancelled (it keeps spamming "I'm still standing")

In debug mode, I can see that the `Task` stored in `unfinished` is indeed marked as Cancelled but obiously the thread is not cancelled / killed.

Why is the thread not killed when the wrapping task is cancelled ?
What should I do to stop the thread ?

```py
import time
import asyncio

def quickTask():
    time.sleep(1)

def infiniteTask():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("I'm still standing")

async def main():
    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait({
            asyncio.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(quickTask)),
            asyncio.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(infiniteTask))
        },
        return_when = "FIRST_COMPLETED"
    )

    for task in unfinished:
        task.cancel()
    await asyncio.wait(unfinished)

    print("  finished : " + str(len(finished))) # print '1'
    print("unfinished : " + str(len(unfinished))) # print '1' 

    
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: There was major error in my answer - you might want to check code again (`asyncio.Event` to `threading.Event`) - sorry for inconvenience!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### EDIT:

Use `threading.Event` instead of `asyncio.Event` - latter is not *Thread Safe!* thanks @martin for pointing it out!

---

### Cause

If we check the definition of `asyncio.to_thread()`:

```py
# python310/Lib/asyncio/threads.py
# ...

async def to_thread(func, /, *args, **kwargs):
    """Asynchronously run function *func* in a separate thread.

    Any *args and **kwargs supplied for this function are directly passed
    to *func*. Also, the current :class:`contextvars.Context` is propagated,
    allowing context variables from the main thread to be accessed in the
    separate thread.

    Return a coroutine that can be awaited to get the eventual result of *func*.
    """
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    func_call = functools.partial(ctx.run, func, *args, **kwargs)
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func_call)
```

It's actually a wrapper of `loop.run_in_executor`.

If we then go into how asyncio's test handle `run_in_executor`:

```py
# python310/Lib/test/test_asyncio/threads.py
# ...

class EventLoopTestsMixin:
    # ...

    def test_run_in_executor_cancel(self):
        called = False

        def patched_call_soon(*args):
            nonlocal called
            called = True

        def run():
            time.sleep(0.05)

        f2 = self.loop.run_in_executor(None, run)
        f2.cancel()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(
                self.loop.shutdown_default_executor())
        self.loop.close()
        self.loop.call_soon = patched_call_soon
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe = patched_call_soon
        time.sleep(0.4)
        self.assertFalse(called)
```

You can see it will wait for `self.loop.shutdown_default_executor()`.

Now let's see how it looks like.

```py
# event.pyi
# ...

class BaseEventLoop(events.AbstractEventLoop):
    # ...

    async def shutdown_default_executor(self):
        """Schedule the shutdown of the default executor."""
        self._executor_shutdown_called = True
        if self._default_executor is None:
            return
        future = self.create_future()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self._do_shutdown, args=(future,))
        thread.start()
        try:
            await future
        finally:
            thread.join()

    def _do_shutdown(self, future):
        try:
            self._default_executor.shutdown(wait=True)
            self.call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_result, None)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_exception, ex)
```

Here, we can see it creates another thread to wait for `_do_shutdown`, which then runs `self._default_executor.shutdown` with `wait=True` parameter.

Then where the shutdown is implemented:

```py
# Python310/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py
# ...

class ThreadPoolExecutor(_base.Executor):
    # ...

    def shutdown(self, wait=True, *, cancel_futures=False):
        with self._shutdown_lock:
            self._shutdown = True
            if cancel_futures:
                # Drain all work items from the queue, and then cancel their
                # associated futures.
                while True:
                    try:
                        work_item = self._work_queue.get_nowait()
                    except queue.Empty:
                        break
                    if work_item is not None:
                        work_item.future.cancel()

            # Send a wake-up to prevent threads calling
            # _work_queue.get(block=True) from permanently blocking.
            self._work_queue.put(None)
        if wait:
            for t in self._threads:
                t.join()
```

When `wait=True` it decides to wait for all thread to be gracefully stops.

From all these we can't see any effort to actually cancel a thread.

To quote from [Trio Documentation](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#putting-blocking-i-o-into-worker-threads):

> Cancellation is a tricky issue here, because **neither Python nor the operating systems it runs on provide any general mechanism for cancelling an arbitrary synchronous function running in a thread.** This function will always check for cancellation on entry, before starting the thread. But once the thread is running, there are two ways it can handle being cancelled:
>
> - If cancellable=False, the function ignores the cancellation and keeps going, just like if we had called sync_fn synchronously. This is the default behavior.
> - If cancellable=True, then this function immediately raises Cancelled. In this case the thread keeps running in background – **we just abandon it to do whatever it’s going to do, and silently discard any return value or errors that it raises.**

So, from these we can learn that there's no way to terminate infinite-loop running in thread.

---

### Workaround

Since now we know we have to design what's going to run in thread with a bit more care, we need a way to signal the thread that we want to stop.

We can utilize [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) for such cases.

Originally I wrote answer with [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) but that is not *Thread Safe!* because we're moving function execution to another thread probably better off not using it.

```py
import time
import asyncio
import threading


def blocking_func(event: threading.Event):
    while not event.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        print("I'm still standing")


async def main():
    event = threading.Event()
    asyncio.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(blocking_func, event))

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    # now lets stop
    event.set()

asyncio.run(main())
```

By checking event on every loop we can see program terminating gracefully.

```
I'm still standing
I'm still standing
I'm still standing
I'm still standing
I'm still standing
I'm still standing

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I believe you may want to use `threading.Event` instead of `asyncio.Event` in the suggested workaround, as `asyncio.Event` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @martin Oops, read comment wrong, you're very right - I just delegated to thread myself, great point!

Comment: @martin description, code, result updated, thanks for head-up - kinda interesting to see now we have one more output before termination, probably that's what `asyncio.Event`'s non-thread safe part was about?