# Asyncio : how to kill a thread in ThreadPoolExecutor by an other coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a code like that :

```py
import asyncio
import time


# long blocking synchronous calls
def long_blocking_sync_calls():
    print('task 2 (thread) : sleeping for a long time')
    time.sleep(1000)
    print('task 2 (thread) : terminate')


# task2, that execute blocking_sync_calls in separate thread
async def task2():
    print('task 2 : running a long blocking call, in a separate thread')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, long_blocking_sync_calls)


# task1
async def task1(task_2):
    print('task 1 : waiting')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('task 1 : cancelling task 2 ..')
    print(str(task_2.cancel()))
    print('task 1 : task 2 cancelled.')


# create tasks and gather
async def run():
    print('creating tasks..')
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(task2())
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(task1(task_2))
    print('tasks created. now gather..')
    await asyncio.gather(
        task_1,
        task_2,
    )
    print('program end')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run())
```

The output is as follow :

```
creating tasks..
tasks created. now gather..
task 2 : running a long blocking call, in a separate thread
task 2 (thread) : sleeping for a long time
task 1 : waiting
task 1 : cancelling task 2 ..
True
task 1 : task 2 cancelled.
... the program never end here ...
```

As you can see, I have multiples coroutines that I gather on.

The `task2` coroutine is particular, because it executes `long blocking calls` (which are not async) in a separate thread.

The problem is that, when the `task1` try to cancel `task2`, it doesn't work.

Question : is there a way to kill the `long_blocking_sync_calls` thread, from the coroutine `task1` ?

Thank you

Comment: [This could be helpful](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task).

Comment: Under what conditions do you want to cancel `blocking_sync_calls`? What will signal to you that you will want it cancelled?

Comment: Thank you @oda. I have enhanced my post. What I need, is that, if `task1` have a problem, the `task2` can be totally killed, even if the thread is being processing a long blocking call

Comment: I just edited my post, with a full not-working PoC Python code

Comment: Sadly you (and python itself) don't have a good way to kill running thread, a similar(yet slightly different) [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71420261/10909029) might help a bit understanding & hopefully getting around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up to a full `asyncio` solution, by avoiding any long blocking synchronous calls, thanks to various libraries.

Comment: What were they?  :)